# How to use SSL for my android spring resttemplate

Tags: android, spring, ssl, resttemplate

I've been using Spring's RestTemplate to access my webservice, but now i need to use ssl. Ive been searching and found a few examples but none that worked (I had a lot of truble with deprecated functions where i cant figure out)

Here is how i use it so far

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
// Add the String message converter
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
// Make the HTTP GET request, marshaling the response to a String
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(urlQuery, String.class, "GetUnit/" + tM.getDeviceId());
}
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.1'
}
```

how do i make this do ssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up throwing away Spring. i was unable to find a solution using Spring.

so now i rely on HttpsUrlConnection and using gson for sending objects

```
public String GetUnit(String url) {
        String result = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL requestedUrl = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) requestedUrl.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
                ((HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                ((HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection).setHostnameVerifier(new BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier());
            }
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1500);
            lastResponseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            result = IOUtil.readFully(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = ex.toString();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```